# AWS Security group inbound traffic blocked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, aws-security-group

I have an AWS EC2 working instance with a security group allowing **inbound traffic from ports 80, 22 and 443** (HTTP, SSH & HTTPS).
[image]
Everything was working fine until I opened a few new ports and deleted the rule allowing HTTPS by mistake. Then of course I couldn't access my website. I checked the ports and added 443 again but I'm still having the same problem. The only thing that worked is **allowing ALL traffic** but this is a major security hole. 
[image]
I have a second AWS instance in another account that has exactly the same security rules and it's working as it should.
What could possibly be wrong?
I double checked that it's the **right security group and the rules had been applied**.
[image]

Ports listening on my server (I'm using Ruby on Rails with nginx)
[image]

VPC network acl inbound rules:
[image]

```
nc -zv <server_ip> 22 and nc -zv <server_ip> 443
```

returns successful on both, when "all traffic" rule is off but still no access

Comment: Please mention in question which security group works and which is not working and which is the instance above is that working instance or non working instance.

Comment: Check ACL Rules if you are inside a VPC.

Comment: Are you sure you deleted 443 by mistake? or it was a different port?

Comment: @AshishBista what is a VPC? I now see a security group with the name "default VPC security group" and it has a rule allows all traffic, but the source is the GROUP ID itself. Both of the security groups has the same VPC ID but I don't know what that means

Comment: @MaxZXL VPC is your private cloud within AWS cloud. If your instance is in VPC, there are a few more extra places you need define access rules. The "default VPC security group" should not affect if it's not attached to your instance. Do you see VPC ID on instance description?

Comment: @AshishBista If he by mistakenly deleted HTTPS port in sec group why are you asking him to check the ACL?

Comment: @error2007s He has brought back that rule as he's shown above with screenshots. So, he should be able to access the instance and port. The other place that he's to look into is ACL.

Comment: Yes but it was working for him before ACL's don't get deleted suddenly. And when he allowing all ports the application works for him. So this is definitely port issue. @MaxZXL Can you give some details about the application what platform it is working on and all that and are you using a load balance ?

Comment: I've noticed that on my other server I set the same options in the default VPC group and the security group I use for the instance. Tried doing the same but still the same issue. I have the same VPC ID for both of them.

@error2007s I'm working with Ruby on Rails with nginx. I try to access the site using https:// so I guess 443 should work...

I don't understand why someone left -1 on my question. If any information is missing or isn't clear enough I would like to know and make it better

Comment: @AshishBista anything?

Comment: @MaxZXL Please also provide details of your ACL rules.

Comment: @AshishBista Sorry for the noob question but ACL is not what I showed in the screenshots? If it is not, then how do I access it?

Comment: @MaxZXL Go to VPC console. On the left pane, you can find Network ACLs under Security section. Select one that your instance uses. Then, check what rules are there in Inbound Rules.

Comment: @AshishBista I've added a screenshot to the thread

Comment: @MaxZXL Can you do one last thing? `nc -zv <server_ip> 22` and `nc -zv <server_ip> 443`

Comment: @AshishBista From the server terminal or a different one?Should I do it after I remove "allow all traffic"? Is that suppose to troubleshoot something or just ping?

Comment: @MaxZXL On your local terminal. That is fine, I believe.

Comment: @AshishBista Says it's successful on both, while "all traffic" is off, but still no access. What could that mean?

Comment: @MaxZXL That means the server port 443 is accessible from your machine. Any updates on this?

Comment: Thank you for showing interest in my issue, but unfortunately everything is the same. It is very weird that it shows that the port is accessible from my machine but I can't access the website... I have no ideas left